# Starting page numbering on page greater than page #1 in Pages '09

Tags: pages, iwork

I want to add page numbers to the header of my document in Apple Pages '09. However, I would like the page numbering to start on page five; i.e. I want pages 1-4 to have no numbers, and for page #1 to start on page five. Is there any way to do this? I tried creating section breaks, but that has no effect on page numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just worked for me.

Create your you four pages.

Click on the last page (4) and then 'insert' a section break.

Now with page 5 selected ( click inside page)

Go to the 'Layout inspector' and set it to:

[image]

Insert Autopage Numbers. Settings:

[image]

You can now insert more pages and the numbers continue.

The first 4 pages have no numbers. And page 5 starts from 1 with the rest continuing on consecutively

Comment: Just notice you want page 5 to be page one. will look at that now.

Comment: Update answer to show how to set start page number

Comment: This is correct except that in your last illustration you show "include number on first page" as being selected. That should not be selected, in my experience. Otherwise, thanks, very helpful!